# How to fix "Exception caught by image resource service"

Tags: flutter, image, dart, exception

I have created a resources folder to store my images.

```
part of 'resources.dart';

    class IconImages {
      IconImages._();
    
      static const String test1 = 'assets/images/test1.jpg';
      static const String test2 = 'assets/images/test2.jpg';
      static const String test3 = 'assets/images/test3.jpg';
    }
```

I write them to the Map collection

```
 final imagesIcon = <int, String>{
    1: IconImages.test1,
    2: IconImages.test2,
    3: IconImages.test3,
  };
```

and then pass the recorded images to the button.

```
 icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon.values.toString())),

// full button

    Column(             
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                            child: IconButton(
                                                icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon.values.toString())),
                                                onPressed: () {},),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 40,),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                            child: IconButton(  
                                                icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon.values.toString())),
                                                onPressed: () {},),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 40,),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                            child: IconButton(
                                                icon:   Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon.values.toString())),
                                                onPressed: () {},), 
                          ),          
                        ],
                      ),
```

When I execute my code, I get the following exception

[image]

Everything works when I transmit the image in this form

```
icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(IconImages.test2)),
```

But when I try to get a path from Map in this way, the above error is obtained

```
 icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon.values.toString())),
```

Comment: are you add those images into your assets folder?

Comment: @eamirho3ein Yes, and I added the path to this folder in pubspec.yaml

Comment: could you print('path =${imagesIcon.values.toString()}');?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your map wrong:

```
IconButton(
  icon: Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[1].toString())),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be because you're passing icons as strings. Instead of using images with a class like:

```
ImageIcon(
     AssetImage("images/icon.png"),
     color: Colors.red,
     size: 24,
),
```

Edit: after recreating the situation in my project I've found the reason behind that. You use `imagesIcon.values.toString()` to pass the value of an Icon. Did you check what this function returns? In my case it returned:

```
(assets/images/test1.jpg, assets/images/test2.jpg,
assets/images/test3.jpg)
```

No wonder the image is unreadable according to flutter because that is not a proper path or file.

Instead you can use your solution like this:

```
imagesIcon.values.elementAt(1) //0,1,2 whatever index you need from map
```

Comment: I do the same thing by simply adding the path to the image to a variable and specifying it.

Comment: I saw the attempt at that but error `thrown when resolving image codec` mostly comes from simple mistakes like bad string parsing or wrong path name when flutter doesn't see the image fileType correctly. Or for some reason would like a different file type like png instead of jpg but that would be stupid in this case. Please try to put the image there directly without extra string defining files and lists.

Comment: I updated the information in the question, but yes when I add. images without Map in this form, "icon: Image(image: AssetImage(IconImages.test2))," everything works. I think the problem is Mar and I'm somehow incorrectly trying to get a link to an image from it

Comment: Update: 

I understand what you mean, it gets the whole list of Map values that don't match the AssetImage. But I get the same error when one value is stored in the Map, not 3, and the path must pass correctly. Please try to leave the value in Map 1 and try